# Invertible elements and identity element in $\mathbb Z_6$ under the circle product

Tags: abstract-algebra, monoid

Let's define the operation $\odot$ on $\mathbb Z_{6}$ as follows:

$$\begin{aligned}x\odot y=x+y+xy\end{aligned}$$

Show:

- $(\mathbb Z_6, \odot)$ is a monoid;
- if $3 \in \mathbb Z_6$ is an invertible element, if so use an appropriate congruential equation to determine its invertible element;
- define all the invertible elements in $\mathbb Z_6$.

I've started proving the last two items first. The element $3$ is not an invertible element in $\mathbb Z_6$ because $gcd(3,6) \neq 1$.

In order to define all the invertible elements in $\mathbb Z_6$ I thought it would be enough to enumerate all the elements $[a] \in \mathbb Z_6 : gcd(a,6)=1$. So I concluded all invertible elements in $\mathbb Z_6$ are:

$$\begin{aligned}\{1+6k:k\in\mathbb Z\} = 1+6 \mathbb Z\end{aligned}$$ and 
$$\begin{aligned}\{5+6k:k\in\mathbb Z\} = 5+6 \mathbb Z\end{aligned}$$

In order to prove $(\mathbb Z_6, \odot)$ to be a monoid, we require $\odot$ to be associative and $\exists \mathbb 1_{\mathbb Z_{6}} : x \odot \mathbb 1_{\mathbb Z_{6}} = \mathbb 1_{\mathbb Z_{6}} \odot x = x$

**Associativity**

$$\begin{aligned}(a \odot b) \odot c = a \odot (b \odot c)\end{aligned}$$
$$\begin{aligned}(a+b+ab) \odot c = a \odot (b+c+bc)\end{aligned}$$
$$\begin{aligned}a+b+ab+c+ac+bc+abc = a+b+c+bc+ab+ac+abc\end{aligned}$$

And the point is proved.

**Identity element**

$$\begin{aligned}a \odot \mathbb 1_{\mathbb Z_{6}} = a\end{aligned}$$
$$\begin{aligned}1_{\mathbb Z_{6}} + a1_{\mathbb Z_{6}} = 0 \end{aligned}$$

... and now I am stuck because I don't know how to proceed in order to evaluate $1_{\mathbb Z_{6}}$.

Is it correct stating $1_{\mathbb Z_{6}} + a1_{\mathbb Z_{6}} = 0 \Rightarrow a1_{\mathbb Z_{6}} = 0$? How do I take it from here?

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_6$ is an abelian group, so it is customary to write its identity element as $0$ - in this case, it is the residue class of $0\mod 6.$ Now there is no guarantee that the identities for $ \odot $ and modular addition will coincide, but why don't you try it and see what you get.

Comment: Further, it's impossible to answer the last two questions without verification of the first. The notion of invertability for this monoid is not the same as for multiplication of residues.

Comment: I think the OP is (confusingly!) using $1_{\mathbb{Z}_6}$ to refer to a hypothetical identity of the structure under consideration, not the identity of $\mathbb{Z}_6$.

Answer (score 3):

First, your problem in particular.

You should not answer the second question first. Your answer is assuming you are talking about the *usual* multiplicative structure of $\mathbb{Z}_6$, but that is not the case. Once you prove that $(\mathbb{Z},\odot)$ is a monoid, the question is asking you to determine whether $3$ is invertible **relative to the operation** $\odot$. So checking whether $\gcd(3,6)=1$ may not do you any good.  Likewise, the third question is not really asking you to find the elements of $\mathbb{Z}_6$ that are invertible under the *usual* multiplication, but rather to find the elements that are invertible **relative to the operation** $\odot$. So you've correctly answered a **different** question from what you are being asked, and incorrectly answered the question you were *really* asked.

So, let's talk about $\odot$.

You've shown that $\odot$ is associative, so that means $(\mathbb{Z}_6,\odot)$ is a semigroup. To prove that it is a monoid, you need to find some element $z$ of $\mathbb{Z}_6$ with the property that $a\odot z=z\odot a = a$ for all $a$. So you need
$$a = a\odot z = a+z+az.$$
Therefore, we need $a=a+z+az$, which means $0=z+az = z(1+a)$. This has to hold for *every* $a\in\mathbb{Z}_6$. So... what must $z$ be?

(Note that since $b\odot a = b+a+ba = a+b+ab=a\odot b$, you in fact can save yourself a bit of work; you don't actually need to check that $z\odot a= a$ also holds).

Once you determine what $z$ is, the second part of the question is asking you to determine whether there exists $a\in\mathbb{Z}_6$ such that $3\odot a = z$.

Finally, the problem asks you to figure out all elements $a\in\mathbb{Z}_6$ with the property that there exists $b\in\mathbb{Z}_6$ such that $a\odot b = z$.

---

Now, general comments. **Do not read this until you attempt the problem as outlined above.**

The operation you are talking about is known as the "circle operation" (sometimes it is defined as $x\odot y = x+y-xy$, in which case some of the pluses signs below need to be turned into minuses, and vice versa).  In a ring, the elements that are invertible under the circle operation are known as "quasi-units", and the group of quasi-units of the ring is known as the "circle group" of the ring. (Associativity of the circle operation guarantees that if $x$ and $y$ are quasi-units, then so is $x\odot y$).

If $R$ is a ring, the identity of the $\odot$ operation is $0_R$, since $x\odot 0_R = x+0_R + x0_r = x$ and $0_R\odot x = 0_R + x + 0_Rx = x$. If $R$ is commutative, then the circle monoid $(R,\odot)$ is commutative.

When $R$ has a multiplicative identity, $1_R$, then the circle group of the ring is isomorphic to the group of units of $R$ by the map $x\mapsto 1_R+x$.

Indeed, if $x$ is quasi-invertible, then there exists $y$ such that $x\odot y = 0_R$ (and $y\odot x = 0_R$ when we don't assume $R$ is commutative). Then $x+y+xy=0_R$, so
$$(1_R+x)(1_R+y) = 1_R + x + y + xy = 1_R.$$

Conversely, if $z$ is a unit in $R$, then there exists $w$ such that $zw=1_R$. Then
$$(z-1_R)\odot(w-1_R) = (z-1_R)+(w-1_R) + (z-1_R)(w-1_R) = z+w-1_R-1_R+zw - z-w-1_R = 0_R$$
so $z-1_R$ is a quasi-unit. Thus, the map is a bijection between quasi-units and units.

Finally, note that $x\odot y + 1_R = x+y+xy+1_R$, and $(x+1_R)(y+1_R) = xy +x+y+1_R$, so the map is a group homomorphism.

Comment: first of all thank you for your making well clear that the operations are relative to the newly defined operation, but now I feel a bit lost because 'til now I've only managed to manipulate in $\mathbb Z_n$ and the _vanilla-flavoured_ operations. So in regard to the identity element, I think that it must be $z = 0$, but now a new problem arises: $3 \odot a = 3+a+3a = 0$: how do I attempt to solve such equation? I guess I can't proceed like I would in $\mathbb Z$ as $$a = -\frac{3}{4}$$ which I think it's not acceptable, right?

Comment: @haunted85: You solve it with congruences. Does there exist an $a$ such that $3+a(3+1)\equiv 0\pmod{6}$? you need $4a\equiv -3\equiv 3\pmod{6}$. Can a multiple of $4$ be congruent modulo $6$ to $3$? All you have to do is check, if you can't think of a better way: test $a=0,1,2,3,4,5$ and see if there is a solution. If not, then $a$ is not $\odot$-invertible.

Comment: thank you, this has helped a lot... I have to ask, what if I had $mod 38$ instead of $mod 6$, in order to verify if there's a solution to that equation, would it be ok using the Euclidean method? Now that I've made myself sure that none of those values is a good fit as a solution how do I get to find out all the invertible elements in $\mathbb Z_{6}$

Comment: @haunted85: The modular equation $ax\equiv b\pmod{n}$ has a solution if and only if $\gcd(a,n)$ divides $b$. This holds no matter what $b$ is. As to finding the invertible elements, you want to find the $a$ for which there exists $b$ such that $a\odot b = 0$ (since $0$ is the $\odot$-identity). This amounts to finding what values of $a$ will allow you to solve $a+b+ab\equiv 0\pmod{6}$. You can write this as $(1+a)b\equiv -a\pmod{6}$. You know that $a\equiv 0$ is possible (take $b\equiv 0$. You know that $a\equiv 3$ is impossible. Check the others; not that many to try, so just try them.